# How to use custom version tables with meta in paper trail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

I wanted to track change of *storages* and store it in a *storage_versions* table which have a column *storage_type* to store the type of storage that is modified. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
class Storage < ApplicationRecord
    has_paper_trail(meta: {storage_type: :storage_type}), class_name: 'StorageVersion'
//additional methods here
end
```

And I've 'StorageVersion' class defined at *app/models/paper_trail/storage_version.rb* like this:

```
class StorageVersion < PaperTrail::Version
    self.table_name = 'storage_versions'
end
```

As far as I know it should work but it isn't. How can I make this work?

**Update**

Sorry for the incomplete question.
I have *versions* table defined(not abstract), *storage_versions* table do have *storage_type* column.

**Solution**

Moved *storage_version.rb* outside of *paper_trail* folder and changed the declaration of `has_paper_trail` to

```
has_paper_trail class_name: 'StorageVersion', meta: { storage_type: :storage_type }
```

like @jemonsanto said. Thank you @jemonsanto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be myriads of reasons why it won't go through:

You haven't posted the schema, so do check there if storage type is declared.

If you don't have the `versions` table then it would surely break.
You can fix that by declaring the base class as an abstract class per [documentation](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#configuration).

Next,

Your class declaration needs to be fixed since it is on a folder, you need to add it to the module `PaperTrail`. Thus, your class should be, `PaperTrail::StorageVersion`.

If you don't wanna do that, you can just remove the class from subfolder and let it reside under `models/`

Your method declaration for `has_paper_trail` seems a bit wonky. You've excluded the class name in the params. Also noticed that you've put your class in `app/models/paper_trail/storage_version`, you need to specify that path in the method declaration.

`has_paper_trail class_name: 'PaperTrail::StorageVersion', meta: { storage_type: storage_type }`

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. And the problem is solved by moving storage_version.rb outside of paper_trail folder and changed the declaration of has_paper_trail in Storage.rb